# Windows 2k8 R2 - Tips to understand and to remember the Group Scopes?

Tags: untagged

I'm studying Active Directory Groups, and have so many confusing about these scopes of Group implementations. I wonder is there any tip, table or picture that outline all these scopes concept?

I'm reading MCTS Self-Paced Configuring Windows Server 2008 Active Directory Training Kit, the table they give in thier book is incorrect I think. So I got stuck in these concepts. I am already aware of Group Types, and the basic purpose of group scope, but I really want to know comprehensively about these concept, preparing for the exam.

Comment: Post the contents of the table that you think is wrong, and why you think it's wrong.

Comment: Are you just wanting an overview of the group scopes and how they apply, when to apply, who can be in those groups, etc?

Comment: There are many contents. Those are the global group explanation (Membership and Available concept for that group scope), the summary table and the lesson review questions. All of them are not connected. I think maybe 1 of them is wrong, but really it's hard to know.

Comment: The Cleaner: That's right. It seems to be good if that's a short summary table or an outline picture I hope.

Comment: try looking at the publisher's website for errata. if there's an error, i bet someone else has noticed it already. publishers of tech books usually post those errors on their website.

Comment: I found them out. The answers were false. That's a good information longneck!
Here is the side: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955243
My problem is at page 882 "Answers marked as correct are incorrect"
Thanks you all!

Comment: Good find, I will answer with some basics if it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully the below helps.  None of this is really written in stone.  Most don't truly adhere to the "rules" of nesting properly or even care.  For instance, in theory you should nest global groups inside domain local groups and then apply permissions, but a lot of people (especially with a single domain) will just make a `Security Group - Global` and assign NTFS permissions, etc. with that global group.  But think about what happens if you suddenly have a trust in place with a 2nd domain and then want to apply the same rights to users in that domain?  Now you have to add a new ACL for a domain local group or universal group to that same NTFS folder since you nest anything from another domain into that original global group.

This graphic is actually pretty good, so I'll include it as reference:

[image]

**Domain Local Groups**

Only visible within the domain, and used to assign permissions on objects in that domain.  You can "nest" inside a domain local group other domain local groups in that domain, as well as add users/computers and global groups from another trusted domain in the same forest.  You can also add universal groups from any trusted domain in the forest.

---

**Global Groups**

Global groups (despite the name) are groups that contain objects only in their own domain.  They can't contain objects from another domain.  Really only used to group objects together, like the Accounting group users into a single Accounting group.  Then that global group is nested inside a Domain Local group and that local group has security rights applied to it.

---

**Universal groups**

These can contain members from any trusted domain in the forest.  Typically you would use these to nest global groups from different domains (say two global groups called `Accounting` in DomainA and in DomainB) and then put the Universal group into a Domain Local group or maybe another Universal group and apply permissions to that group.

---

**Technical Resources for further reading:**

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755692%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776499%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

http://itsupportsnippets.com/active-directory-group-scopes-types/

Comment: That's a good basic concept. I like the table, so the term "trusted domain" here is the trusted external domain, right?

Comment: Yes, `trusted domain` is any domain you've setup an NT/AD trust with (usually a 2 way transitive, but not necessarily).